# Snappy Compression not working due to tmp folder previliges

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, snappy

I have a problem whenever i am trying to store my data in a compressed format with pig, Sqoop, or Spark. I know the problem is with mounting our tmp folder to nonexec and this causes for instance snappy to give me this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-fe4e30d0-e4a5-4b1a-ae31-fd1861117288-libsnappyjava.so: /tmp/snappy-1.1.2-fe4e30d0-e4a5-4b1a-ae31-fd1861117288-libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

The solutions that i found in the internet is that either mount the tmp folder to exec which is not an option for me as the sysadmin won't allow it due to security concerns.The other option is to change the java opts execution path to some other paths instead of tmp.

I have tried the following approach, but it didn't solve the problem.
add these lines to hadoop-env.sh and sqoop-env

> export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/newpath"
>   export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/newpath"

I would appreciate if you guys have any other solutions that could solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Saeed Soltani. were you able to resolve this issue?If so how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

For other users with this issue, try starting Hive with

`hive --hiveconf org.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/../`

and supply a location that can execute