# SPARK Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.0.4.1-libsnappyjava

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am running `CDH 5.16` standalone singlenode in a `RHEL 7` Server.
I have written a simple spark code that reads a text file from `HDFS` and load it as parquet file in a separate location in `HDFS`. But when ever i am running this code in the server(i am using `SBT` to build jar and deploy it in cluster using spark-submit), following error is thrown:

```
19/06/07 12:56:04 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
19/06/07 12:56:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ak_bng
19/06/07 12:56:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ak_bng
19/06/07 12:56:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(ak_bng); users with modify permissions: Set(ak_bng)
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 44220.
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.188.223.5:36304]
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO Remoting: Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.188.223.5:36304]
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 36304.
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-c38a27e3-c483-4f56-ab7f-56e4c1be0832
19/06/07 12:56:05 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.0 MB
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.188.223.5:4040
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO spark.SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/ak_bng/spark_jars/Simple_Project-assembly-1.0.jar at spark://10.188.223.5:44220/jars/Simple_Project-assembly-1.0.jar with timestamp 1559892366578
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 46170.
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 46170
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO storage.BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:46170 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 46170)
19/06/07 12:56:06 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
19/06/07 12:56:07 INFO scheduler.EventLoggingListener: Logging events to hdfs://indelsrv185.in.kworld.kpmg.com:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory/local-1559892366602
19/06/07 12:56:07 INFO spark.SparkContext: Registered listener com.cloudera.spark.lineage.ClouderaNavigatorListener
19/06/07 12:56:08 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://10.188.223.5:8020/user/ak_bng/products on driver
19/06/07 12:56:08 INFO parquet.ParquetRelation: Listing hdfs://10.188.223.5:8020/user/ak_bng/categories on driver
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:312)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:219)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:44)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version$lzycompute(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$5.apply(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$toString$5.apply(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.dataSource$lzycompute$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameWriter$$dataSource$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$save$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.executeAndCallQEListener(DataFrameWriter.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:370)
        at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:169)
        at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/snappy-1.0.4.1-libsnappyjava.so: /tmp/snappy-1.0.4.1-libsnappyjava.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNativeLoader.load(SnappyNativeLoader.java:39)
        ... 65 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version$lzycompute(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.org$apache$spark$io$SnappyCompressionCodec$$version(CompressionCodec.scala:168)
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec.<init>(CompressionCodec.scala:152)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.io.CompressionCodec$.createCodec(CompressionCodec.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$setConf(TorrentBroadcast.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
        at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:106)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.dataSource$lzycompute$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrameWriter$$dataSource$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$save$1.apply$mcV$sp(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.executeAndCallQEListener(DataFrameWriter.scala:154)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:172)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:370)
        at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:169)
        at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyCompressionCodec$.liftedTree1$1(CompressionCodec.scala:169)
        ... 53 more
19/06/07 12:56:08 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/06/07 12:56:08 INFO ui.SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.188.223.5:4040
19/06/07 12:56:08 INFO spark.MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO scheduler.OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO Remoting: Remoting shut down
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/06/07 12:56:09 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-111712ef-39a8-41b6-bf6d-5d317d954fa1
```

spark submit command:
`spark-submit --class SimpleApp --master local[8]  /home/ak_bng/spark_jars/Simple_Project-assembly-1.0.jar`.

I went through few links to resolve this issue([Snappy Compression not working due to tmp folder previliges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211407/snappy-compression-not-working-due-to-tmp-folder-previliges), [Apache Spark - Parquet / Snappy compression error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063940/apache-spark-parquet-snappy-compression-error), ) but none couldn't really provide a solution for this.

I had run Spark on `HDFS` (separate installation) successfully without any errors before. The problem started coming once `CDH`was installed.
I am new to setting up cluster and quite don't understand what the issue is here and how to resolve it. Can some one help please shed some light on this.

I am using:

```
CDH 5.16
Spark 1.6.0
Server OS: RHEL 7
Hadoop 2.6
```